# How to read/write a document to shared storage in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

The android developer documentation explains how to save a document to shared storage without needing permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file). This is the linked code snipped:

```kotlin
// Request code for creating a PDF document.
const val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/json"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "backup.json")

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

The problem is that there is no `startActivityForResult()` that takes those arguments.

My goal is to write a json file to shared storage and then read it again later so it can be used as a backup.

Comment: A text file? A pdf document is a text file?

Comment: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT should work. Unclear which problem you have. Please elaborate.

Comment: The method is here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int), but since some time it becomes deprecated:  
```This method has been deprecated in favor of using the Activity Result API which brings increased type safety via an ActivityResultContract and the prebuilt contracts for common intents available in androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts```

Comment: I don't understand what all the moving parts are that are needed to make this work. Since the documentation code is broken it would be nice if there was a small working example of reading and writing to shared storage.